# Proof by induction when I have $P(n)$ implies $P(n \pm1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, induction

I seek to prove that the number of inversions in a permutation is the length of the word (letters of the form $(i,i+1)$).  I land on $P(n)$ implies $P(n \pm 1)$.  I can't quite convince myself that I'm done or that this isn't strong enough to conclude $P(n)$ for all $n$.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Add more context to the question: how did you land on this? From the little you have written all one can say is that answer is just "no": it's not strong enough for induction to work to just know that $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$ or $P(n-1)$ (assuming this is what you mean). If you mean $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$ AND $P(n-1)$ then yes this is enough.

Comment: let P be a permutation, s be a letter (i.e s=(i,i+1)). Base; If Length(P)=0 then P is the identity map and clearly inv(P)=0.  If Length (P)= k = inv(P) for Permutations of Length k, then Length (Ps)= inv(P) +/- 1= k+/-1. This is where I'm stuck.  Sorry for poor formatting but I think its clear enough?